# DRY Pytest Fixtures

Tags: python, flask, refactoring, pytest, fixtures

I currently have a set of pytest unit tests in a flask app in a similar fashion as below. I have set up fixtures to test multiple scenarios. They are also separated into classes to test different API endpoints.

However, note that many of the fixtures use the same test/login functions and in general the tests seem bloated. Would you be able to recommend best practices to DRY/refactor the below? I'm aware you can do multiple asserts under one test, but I feel separating them out lets you see at what point the tests fails better. All recommendations appreciated.

```
class TestSetOne:

    # Test response for successful matches
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def matching_data(self):
        test = app.test_client(self)
        token = login("111", "asdfasdf")
        data = {
            "phoneNumber": "+1 555-412-1235"
        }
        response = test.post(
            '/phone_search', 
            headers={
                "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(token)
            },
            json=data
        )
        return response
        
    def test_matching_data_status_code(self, matching_data):
        status_code = matching_data.status_code
        assert status_code == 200

    def test_matching_data_type(self, matching_data):
        response_data = matching_data.json
        assert isinstance(response_data, list)

    def test_matching_data_content(self, matching_data):
        response_data = matching_data.json
        assert response_data is not None

    # Test response for no matches
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def no_match_data(self):
        test = app.test_client(self)
        token = login("111", "asdfasdf")
        data = {
            "phoneNumber": "1234567890"
        }
        response = test.post(
            '/phone_search', 
            headers={
                "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(token)
            },
            json=data
        )
        return response
        
    def test_no_match_data_status_code(self, no_match_data):
        status_code = no_match_data.status_code
        assert status_code == 200

    def test_no_match_data_type(self, no_match_data):
        response_data = no_match_data.json
        assert isinstance(response_data, list)

    def test_no_match_data_content(self, no_match_data):
        response_data = no_match_data.json
        assert response_data == []

    # Test bad input data response
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def invalid_data(self):
        test = app.test_client(self)
        token = login("111", "asdfasdf")
        data = {
            "phoneNumber": 17185783339
        }
        response = test.post(
            '/phone_search', 
            headers={
                "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(token)
            }
        )
        return response

    def test_invalid_data_status_code(self, invalid_data):
        status_code = invalid_data.status_code
        assert status_code == 400

    def test_invalid_data_content(self, invalid_data):
        response_data = invalid_data.json
        assert response_data is None
        
    # Test no input data response
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def no_data(self):
        test = app.test_client(self)
        token = login("111", "asdfasdf")
        response = test.post(
            '/phone_search', 
            headers={
                "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(token)
            }
        )
        return response

    def test_no_data_status_code(self, no_data):
        status_code = no_data.status_code
        assert status_code == 400

    def test_no_data_content(self, no_data):
        response_data = no_data.json
        assert response_data is None

    # Test for Unauthorized
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def no_auth(self):
        test = app.test_client(self)
        data = {
            "phoneNumber": "+1 555-412-1235"
        }
        response = test.post(
            '/phone_search',
            json=data
        )
        return response

    def test_no_auth_status_code(self, no_auth):
        status_code = no_auth.status_code
        assert status_code == 401


class TestSetTwo:

    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def no_auth(self):
        test = app.test_client(self)
        token = login("111", "asdfasdf")
        data = {
            "user_id": "asdfasdf"
        }
        response = test.post(
            '/user_search',
            json=data
        )
        return response

    ~ etc ~
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with separate tests for separate fucntionality (though I would probably have made one `test_invalid_data` test instead of two). You could also make a base fixture and configure only the data (via `request`) if you want to avoid to repeat the common part.

Comment: Your tests are well parametrizable. Read about function [parametrizing](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/parametrize.html). And you misuse fixture, no need to test the result of the fixture, the fixture provides auxiliary data for the test

Comment: @AlexNoname Hi could you further clarify? I am reading up on parameterizing and seems easy with simple data types, but I don't know about encapsulating the result of a whole endpoint. How am I using the fixture incorrectly, I need to test API endpoints with varying input data to determine whether it's the result I'm looking for?